# Bootmetro menu template

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-metro

So I used firebug to inspect part of the css being applied to a drop down menu in [Bootmetro](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/hub.html).

You can see here that the `a:hover:active` is responsible for the hover over colour. In this case bootmetro has it set to blue:

[image]

Firebug showed that the css line responsible was in bootstrap.css at line 2821:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
}
```

However when changing the `background-color: #0081c2` to something different it remains the same when tested. Firebug shows that if I change the backgroound color it changes  using firebug, but yet it is not being applied when I manually apply it to the css file.

I tryed changing all the settings to see if anything would be applied and nothing seems to:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  color: #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #666666;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666, #666666);
}

.dropdown-menu .active > a,
.dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
  color: #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #666666;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    outline: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
}
```

I cant figure out if something is over-riding the setting and was wondering if anyone can help.

Comment: use the `!important` as `background-color: #666666 !important;`

Comment: Hey thanks but still no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your browser hold a cache of the css file so you may want to try clear all cache and reload.

Comment: r0dney you were correct. All that effort for nothing. Do you know how you can disable that in firefox? Might be useful to others who come across this question.

Comment: @JungleBoogie There's a setting in Advanced-Network that allows you to  override automatic cache management and set the limit to 0MB.